# Error al insertar DateTime Mysql y PDO

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

estoy insertando un DateTime en Mysql con php y Ajax el problema radica en que el ajax envia la fecha correcta, Php la recibe bien pero en la BD se inserta incorrectamente, tengo lo siguiente:

Ajax:

```
  var fecha_inicio = $("#modalEvento #fecha_inicio").val();
  var hora_inicio = $("#modalEvento #hora_inicio").val();
  var fecha_fin = $("#modalEvento #fecha_fin").val();
  var hora_fin = $("#modalEvento #hora_fin").val();
  start = fecha_inicio + " "+ hora_inicio;
  end = fecha_fin + " " + hora_fin;
  $.ajax({
   url:"incld/insert.php",
   type:"POST",
   data:{
    title:nombre, 
    start:start, 
    end:end
   },
   success:function(){
    $("#modalEvento").modal('hide');
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar();
    calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
    swal("Evento Agregado !!", "", "success");
   }
  })
```

Con esto obtengo los datos tanto Fecha como hora de los input respectivos es decir algo asi:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Fecha de Inicio</label>
         <input type="date" name="fecha_inicio" id="fecha_inicio" class="form-control" >
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Hora de Inicio</label>
        <input type="time" name="hora_inicio" id="hora_inicio" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Fecha Finalización</label>
         <input type="date" name="fecha_fin" id="fecha_fin" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Hora de Finalización</label>
        <input type="time" name="hora_fin" id="hora_fin" class="form-control" required="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

En php los recibe asi:

```
$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=agenda', 'dbmasteruser', 'enjoyprocess23');
     $query = "
     INSERT INTO event 
     (title, start_event, end_event) 
     VALUES (:title, :start_event, :end_event)
     ";
     $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
     $statement->execute(
      array(
       ':title'  => $_POST['title'],
       ':start_event' => $_POST['start'],
       ':end_event' => $_POST['end']
      )
     );
```

con esto se inserta los datos pero por alguna razon la hora se cambia es decir por ajax envio esto:

```
start: 2019-04-30+10:30
end: 2019-04-30+11:30
```

ahora en mysql me muestra asi:

```
start: 2019-04-30 05:30:00
end: 2019-04-30 06:30:00
```

Al ejecutar: **SHOW CREATE TABLE** muestra lo siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(300) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `start_event` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_event` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=52 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci
```

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia..!!

Comment: El datatime, no tiene formato al ser almacenado. por lo que entiendo tu problema es el formato con la que se almacena?

Comment: en efecto guarda incorrecto la hora.. como muestro en el detalle de mi pregunta..

Comment: Quítale el signo `+` cambiándolo por un espacio antes de insertar.

Comment: Otra cosa que llama la atención es **el color sospechoso de tu variable `end`**, evita usarlo, llama a las variables `dateStart` y `dateEnd` en Javascript. Puede que haya un problema de palabra reservada. Es extraño ese signo de `+` cuando no lo estás pasando.

Answer (score 1):

Puede que la hora se modifique a causa del signo de `+`.

Dado que conviene siempre verificar tus variables POST. Podrías asignarlas con un ternario y al mismo tiempo aprovechas para cambiar el `+` por un espacio, lo cual quitaría el problema con el campo de fecha.

```
$title=!empty( $_POST['title'] ) ? $_POST['title'] : NULL;
$start=!empty( $_POST['start'] ) ? str_replace("+", " ",$_POST['start']) : NULL;
$end  =!empty( $_POST['end'] )   ? str_replace("+", " ",$_POST['end'])   : NULL;

if ( $title && $start && $end ) {
$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=agenda', 'dbmasteruser', 'enjoyprocess23');
     $query = "
     INSERT INTO event 
     (title, start_event, end_event) 
     VALUES (:title, :start_event, :end_event)
     ";
     $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
     $arrParams=
      array(
       ':title'  => $title,
       ':start_event' => $start,
       ':end_event' => $end
      )
     $statement->execute($arrParams);
} else {
    echo "Faltan datos en el POST";
}
```

Si aún así no funciona, podría ser un problema de zona horaria o de configuración en la base de datos. Prueba a hacer una inserción a mano, desde el manejador.

Comment: Gracias agregando tu codigo persiste el error por ajax envio la fecha: "2019-04-30 15:30:00" y MySql las muestra en la DB '2019-04-30 10:30:00'

Comment: ¿Parece que resta 5 horas siempre? ¿No habrá algún `TRIGGER` o algo que modifique el dato. Revisa la constitución de la tabla también con `SHOW CREATE TABLE NombreDeTabla`  @DiegoAvila

Comment: he editado mi pregunta con el resultado de dicha consulta..!!

Comment: @DiegoAvila puede que sea un desfase entre el timezone de MySQL y el de PHP. Puedes comparar ambos, lanzando una consulta como esta **desde PHP**: `select @@session.time_zone;`  y mostrando el resultado. Y para PHP haces esto: `echo date_default_timezone_get()`;

Comment: en php obtengo " It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings…”" y en MYSQL obtengo "UTC"

Comment: @DiegoAvila prueba a ejecutar esta consulta en el manejador: `SET time_zone = SYSTEM;` y luego prueba de nuevo la inserción.

Comment: gracias, pero aun persiste dicho error, pero  es curioso que al traer o mostrar los datos de mysql mediante un foreach muestra la hora correcta que se envio x ajax.. pero en mysql muestra otra diferente..!!

Comment: @DiegoAvila ¿qué muestra esta consulta en el manejador: **`SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;`**?

Comment: muestra "UTC" y "SYSTEM"...

Comment: A mi me parece que ese `UTC` es la causa del problema. En mi BD los dos valores son `SYSTEM`.  Intenta esto: `SET @@session.time_zone = SYSTEM;
SET @@global.time_zone = SYSTEM;` y luego verifica de nuevo: `SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;`  y... dime una cosa, ¿tu objeto PDO es manipulado cuando creas la conexión?  revisa si le pasas atributos que modifiquen la zona horaria o algo así.

Comment: apesar de realizar los cambios con esas sentencias.. se mantiene en UTC y SYSTEM..

Comment: Pero me da la impresion que es por el Servidor que es de Amazon WS..

Comment: @DiegoAvila [revisa esto](https://aws.amazon.com/de/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-change-time-zone/). Y si te sigue dando problemas es mejor que contactes con el servicio técnico de Amazon. Es muy extraño, pero parece que efectivamente AWS tiene `UTC` como timezone por defecto. Si vas a trabajar mucho con horas, cuéntale a ellos el problema para que te orienten mejor sobre qué configuración debes tener para trabajar sin errores en PHP. A mi me funciona bien con ambos valores en `SYSTEM`.